# Can both unapply and unapplySeq be defined in the same extractor

Tags: scala

I have following code that aims to define unapply and unapplySeq in the same extractor

```
  test("pattern matching define unapply and unapplySeq") {
    object A {
      def unapply(arg: String): Option[(String, String)] = Some((arg, arg))

      def unapplySeq(arg: String): Option[Seq[String]] = Some(arg.split(" "))
    }

    def x = "hello world"

    x match {
      case A(a, b) => println("unapply matched", a, b)
      case A(a, b, _*) => println("unapplySeq matched", a, b)
    }


  }
```

But it seems not working,when I run this test case, it cause compiling error and complains that

```
Error:(292, 12) Star pattern must correspond with varargs or unapplySeq
      case A(a, b, _*) => println("unapplySeq matched", a, b)
```

I wonder whether it is possible to define both unapply and unapplySeq in the same extractor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this rather-dated-but-still-informative [Scala blog entry](https://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2009/09/extract-sequences-unapplyseq.html):

> **Note**: if both unapply and unapplySeq are defined only unapply is used.

And, indeed, tests appear to bear this out. One or the other works, but not both.

---

**compiler errors explained**

Due to the varargs notation (`_*`), the pattern `A(a, b, _*)` can only be recognized by `unapplySeq()`, but if you have both `unapply()` and `unapplySeq()` defined then only the `unapply()` is seen and the compiler is unable to make the pattern conform to the method definition.

If you comment out the `unapply()` definition, `unapplySeq()` will recognize, and parse, either of your `case` patterns (whichever one comes first since they both match).

Comment: Thanks @jwvh for the answer, it makes sense.